# uwsgi reloading python application on its own

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

So I am using uwsgi to host python flask server.  The command to start the server is :-

```
uwsgi 
--socket 127.0.0.1:8000
--pythonpath=/home/ubuntu 
--wsgi-file /home/ubuntu/application.py 
--callable application 
--master 
--workers 2 
--idle 30
--pidfile /home/ubuntu/server.pid 
--logto /tmp/server.log 
--lazy
```

application.py is a simple flask application which has an endpoint /health which looks like

```
@app.route("/health")
def namaste():
    logging.info('Namaste')
```

I went inside the machine hosting this app, changed the logging.info statement to  `logging.info('Namaste Fella')` and found out that ***'Namaste Fella' got returned even without reloading the uwsgi server.***

I would expect that any new code in my python app will get picked up only when the uwsgi server is reloaded (`uwsgi --reload /home/ubuntu/server.pid`).

Am I missing something?

Comment: you requested idle mode + lazy. So every 30 seconds of inactivity your instance is shutdown and restarted again at the first request. Just as a note --lazy is discouraged by 2 years. Use --lazy-apps

Comment: Why your route doesn't return anything? You should make a response... are you doing that??? Please complete your sample code.

Comment: Sweet! that worked, removed --idle option, did not really need it. though from documentation it's not clear why --lazy-apps is more preferable or what is the diff between lazy and lazy-apps.

Comment: @ed_heck it is explained here http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html